# Email WCF traces to me

Tags: wcf, trace

So I've recently figured out how to turn on the WCF traces which creates an svclog file on my server and this is awesome.  But the problem I have is I don't have direct access to the server where I'm working on my web service so everytime I need to look at the trace file I have to get someone else here at my office to log onto the server for me then I have to upload the trace file to a cloud server because its usually too big to email and then go through weeks worth of requests to find what I want to analyze.

Long story short I want to know if there is a way with trace logging for me to send an email to myself of every trace that gets stored?

Comment: I can't say with certainty that it can't be done, but I'm not 100% sure it'd be the best solution either.  You could be setting yourself up for a huge amount of e-mail (maybe even overloading the server).  Why not ask your system admins for read-only access to the server and the folder where the log files are?

Comment: Another idea would be to see if they could set up a batch job that would upload the trace logs to the cloud server every x period, that way you'd always have (relatively, depending on the frequency) up-to-date logs available.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the responses.  I'm not terribly worried about the email load as we already do quite a bit of alert service stuff like this elsewhere but not for traces although I see your point.  Unfortunately the option of asking for access to the servers around here is more complicated than buying a house.  I've supposedly been in the approval process since I started working here 2 years ago and I don't expect anything soon.  The second option you mentioned is probably what I will end up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be "no" there is no way to email traces using the svclog.  There are other ways to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a custom trace listener to log to DB or email.  [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) or [Nlog](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Mail_target) have some of those already built in.  I've used both and prefer NLog over Log4net due to Nlog having new functionality support.

If you want to create your own from scratch. Look at [this](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/04/writing-an-email-custom-trace-listener-for-a-wcf-service/) guys solution for an example how to.